# Pose Detection operation mode and c++API

Tags: google-mlkit

I am very grateful to the Google team for providing the ML Kit API. I encountered some problems when using Pose Detection. When using images for pose estimation, I found that the API uses a thread-like asynchronous calculation. I don't know if other forms of API will be provided, because we want to calculate each frame of image in use, and then need to process the calculation result of each frame. In addition, will C++ API be provided? I think android ndk and c++ will be more suitable for model deployment.

Answer (score 1):

ML Kit does not provide C++ API. If you prefer to use pose detection in C++ / Native code, check out [BlazePose](https://google.github.io/mediapipe/solutions/pose). Here's their launch [blog post](https://ai.googleblog.com/2020/08/on-device-real-time-body-pose-tracking.html).

Comment: But the current BlazePose does not support full body models.

Comment: The "Pose Landmark Model (BlazePose Tracker)" should track landmarks for the full body per https://google.github.io/mediapipe/solutions/pose